# excel function: countif greater than date or blank

Tags: microsoft-excel

So far I have this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<"&C1, B:B, OR(">"&C2,"="&""))
```

Everything works fine except the OR and the: "="&"". I'm not sure if I'm not checking for blanks properly or if the OR shouldn't be used here.

If there's a better way to do this than a single `COUNTIFS()`, let me know

Comment: You will need to do two countifs() and add them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up summing two countifs since it's a little easier for me to look back at and understand:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,"<"&C1,B:B,">"&C2),COUNTIFS(A:A,"<"&C1,B:B,"="&""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach that bypasses COUNTIFS() altogether:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10<C1)*((B1:B10>C2)+(B1:B10="")))
```

The three expressions in the innermost parentheses produce an array of logical values, but the arithmetic operations convert `TRUE` and `FALSE` to 1 and 0.  The addition is equivalent to the `OR()` operation and the multiplication is equivalent to `AND()`.

So the result of the arithmetic operations is an array with 1 wherever the A range is `< C1` and the B range is either `> C2` or blank.  Then `SUMPRODUCT()` adds up the 1's in the array.

You can't reference the entire Column B in the last expression though, so you would have to adjust the ranges to fit your situation.

Comment: great answer! "The addition is equivalent to the OR() operation"  - this need to be managed carefully, in this formula it's true only for conditions which are exclusive and can't both be true at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, Máté. I hadn't thought about the situation where both conditions are true. It's not a problem here fortunately since a cell can never be both >C2 and blank. But you raise a very good point, and thanks for pointing it out.